# Medir área de objetos em imagens

Tags: android

Pesquisei sobre o assunto e estou estudando opencv para android porque acho que esse é o caminho para detectar objetos em imagens (no meu caso as manchas de doenças). Podem fechar a pergunta e quando eu estiver em uma fase mais adiantada volto aqui se tiver dúvidas. De qualquer forma Obrigado a todos pelo interesse.